# Need help with demonstrative pronouns

Tags: pronoun

I have an assignment for German class to write a letter, expressing some kind of problem. I won't go deep into the subject, I just need help with some demonstrative pronouns, the first sentence being:

> ... es war ein anderer Koffer! Er war auch rot, aber das ist nicht genug, um meinen zu werden.

This thing, I know werden has 2 nominatives, but usually in an *um...zu* clause there's no subject, so I have no idea with this one, my gut, if any :D, tells me it should be *meinen*.

The other sentence I want to include (again regarding a *Koffer*) is:

> Und keiner war doch meiner!

I'm pretty sure about the *keiner*, but not so much about *meiner*. We've done some exercises about demonstrative pronouns, but they were neither that many, nor were they that challenging. Anyway, thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: If the problem is that you want a subject in the subordinate clausule, I think you can use *damit* instead of an *um ...zu* clause.

Comment: Ok, but how would is it supposed to be with an _um...zu_ clause

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. You say you have problems with demonstrative pronouns, but all the time you are talking about possessive pronouns. The only demonstrative pronoun in your example is `das`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, that you mean you have problems with *possessive pronouns*, in this case `mein`.

You are correct, that `werden` demands a nominative object. So a usual sentence with `werden` has two nominative groups: the subject and the nominative object. You are also correct, that an expanded infinitive group (for example started by `um`) doesn't have a subject. But it can still have nominative objects as in this case. So you need to put `mein` in nominative.

(I'm not quite sure, if you really mean `werden` and not `sein`. Just in case: You should use `sein` if you want to express, that you indeed own this `Koffer` or not. You should use `werden` if you want to express, that you want to buy this `Koffer` or not.)

So the first sentence should be:

> … es war ein anderer Koffer! Er war auch rot, aber das ist nicht genug, um mein zu sein/werden. [High register]
>
> … es war ein anderer Koffer! Er war auch rot, aber das ist nicht genug, um meiner zu sein/werden. [Normal register for spoken or written language]

Your second example is grammatically correct, but the `doch` doesn't make any sense in that position. Either:

> Und doch war keiner meiner. [= And yet, none was mine.]

or

> Und keiner war meiner. [= And none was mine.]

Comment: tyvm, helped me a lot :)

Comment: k, just did, didn't know about that option :)